# how to read xml in python with a specific tag attribute?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a xml tag and I am using below code in python to read this tag but I only want to get the data when type = "Actual" otherwise ignore. Currently I get the value for each of them i.e.. 40,50,60.

xml tag:

```
 <student type="Actual">40</student>
 <student type="estimated">50</student>
 <student>60</student>
```

Python Code:

```
student = root.find("./student")
```

Please could you advise the change required in this syntax.

Comment: Is `student = root.find("./student>` supposed to be Python or XML?

Comment: this is a python code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to list all nodes with the "Actual type" attribute :

```
students = root.findall('./student[@type="Actual"]')
```

Comment: I needed a trailing / to make this work: `root.findall('./student[@type="Actual"]/')`